# Getting error using ConvertFrom-Json in Powershell for an incoming PHP parameter (json_eoncoded array) using the EXEC function in PHP

Tags: php, json, powershell

Getting error using ConvertFrom-Json in Powershell for an incoming PHP parameter (json_eoncoded array) using the EXEC function in PHP

PHP Code:

```php
$psPath = "powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass  -NoProfile ";
$psDIR = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\";
$psScript = "ps_scripts.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript." 2>&1 "; 


$parameter_2 = "test";
$array = array("Peter"=>24, "Ben"=>"Hello");
$encoded_data = json_encode($array);
exec($runCMD . "example_function_name \"" . $encoded_data . "\"" . " \"" . $parameter_2 . "\"", $output, $retval);
```

Powershell Code:  ps_scripts.ps1

```
$arguments = $args;
function example_function_name
{
  $sData = $arguments[1] | ConvertFrom-Json
  echo $sData;
}

# Invoking the function
$sb = (get-command $args[0] -CommandType Function).ScriptBlock
invoke-command -scriptblock $sb
```

Error:

```
Array ( [0] => At line:1 char:70 [1] => + ... htdocs\ps_scripts.ps1 example_function_name {Peter:24,Ben:Hell ... [2] => + ~ [3] => Missing argument in parameter list. [4] => + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException [5] => + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument [6] => ) 1
```

Comment: take a look here >>> How do I extract data from JSON with PHP? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: What is `$runCMD`? FWIW `$args` inside the function is not the same `$args` as outside

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen have updated the code about $runCMD, kindly suggest